# Proper grammar regarding Bulletproofs

Tags: terminology, confidential-transactions

For non-native speakers talking about Bulletproofs with correct grammar is tricky.
I tried to use [the white paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf) as a reference, but it is not consistent. Even in the abstract it mixes plural and singular.

> Bulletproofs are especially [...] Moreover, Bulletproofs supports...

1. Should I use plural of singular after Bulletpoofs?
2. Bulletproofs are often abbreviated as BP. Is this a good abbreviation or BPs or something else would be better?
3. If BP is the correct way to abbreviate, then how should it be used? "BP is" or "BP are"?

Comment: Is/are is fine depending on surrounding structure. i.e. BP is an enhancement vs BP are an enhancement. In that case, both are fine.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56574/should-i-use-support-or-supports-with-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the bulletproofs research or the bulletproofs topic, use "is".

If you're talking about the individual proofs, use "are".

- Bulletproofs is shaping the future.
- Bulletproofs is an important protocol.
- Bulletproofs are short and don't require trusted setup.
- Bulletproofs are going to replace the usual signatures.
- Bulletproofs is going to replace the current signature protocol.